How are USB-C cables so thin?
Looking at the plug of a USB-C cable, there are 24 different pins. With a Micro USB cable, each pin corresponds to one wire inside the cable. In my understanding, this means that a USB-C to USB-C cable should have 24 individual wires inside.
How is a USB-C cable able to be so thin, or does the cable have less wires somehow?

each pin corresponds to one wire inside the cable ... not quite ... the plug is reversible

A basic USB 2.0 type C cable only has USB D+/D-, Vcc, gnd, and CC.  The superspeed pairs are optional and most cables do not have them.  Cables that do, especially thunderbolt cables are noticably thicker. And pins are duplicated to allow reversibility but they don't use redundant wires.

@jsotola Being reversible doesn't mean that each wire is connected to two pins, though.  That's one way to implement reversibility, but it's wasteful, and it's not how USB-C is done.  (Instead, only the power, ground, and USB2.0 signals are duplicated.  The socket uses software to detect the orientation of the plug and route the other signals accordingly.)

DATAPOINT  I yell this (but not from rooftops :-) ) as it's liable to be of interest and may be unknown. Even when fully wire equipped some of the signals are not fully symmetric. The USB2 differential pair D+/D- only appears on one side of the plug. These signals need to be connected in the plug to allow reversibility. || CC1 and CC2 are reversible in the cable but plugs only have CC1, with CC2 being replaced by Vcon - a power feed to power any in cable electronics. || NB - E&OE - a poor desription but MUCH good material here https://wiki2.org/en/USB-C

Well, by using thin wires of course.
That they're rated to handle the current they are (~2A), is... kind of ludicrous, but how the copper is allocated, matters.  And, they might not be rated for full current.
The one saving grace is, they're short so resistance isn't as big of an issue, and as long as the internal temperature seems to be okay, there you have it.  Until you don't, and, failing connectors are a notable problem (the equally tiny contacts heat up more, they wear quickly, etc.), as well as fraying cables themselves (foil in particular doesn't flex well, and then the rough broken edge can dig into the insulation, fatigue the braid, and further breakdown ensues).
Food for thought, consider this picture by TubeTime:

Seems to be a special one, using micro-coax instead of twisted pairs; if all the center conductors are VBUS as labeled, the shields must be serving as GND.  Only the USB 2.0 pair uses foil.
Another one shows a more typical foil-wrapped pairs construction:

Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cross_section_of_a_10Gbps_USB_cable.jpg
In both of these examples, the smaller conductors around the side are probably CC/SBU 1/2.  On this one, they appear to be individually foil wrapped, except for the yellow wire strangely.  Rule is mm, so this cable is ~5mm across, not terribly thin, but they can make them thinner by basically shrinking all dimensions proportionally, give or take what they can get away with for the power wires (e.g., shrinking the data pairs more to keep the power wires large).  Also, the CC pins might be wired to a circuit that enumerates the cable's current rating, permitting thinner construction.
Smaller transmission lines have increased losses, restricting the maximum length in a given SuperSpeed mode; it's no accident that most USB3 cables are on the short side.  I haven't looked up the typical specs across the range of available cable sizes and lengths, but I expect the thinner ones aren't available as long due to signal loss.
You can find more cross-sections and close-ups of common and vintage electronics in: Oskay and Schlaepfer, Open Circuits, 2022, No Starch Press, ISBN 9781718502345, https://nostarch.com/open-circuits

My excellent Huawei power bank came with a 1m 6A USB-C cable. Official spec goes as high as 5A @ 48V = 240W.

The unshielded yellow wire in the second picture is probably Vconn (power for any electronics in the cable itself that need it). On a cable that doesn’t actually use it (which I suspect describes the cable that picture is from), it still needs to be passed through (it’s important for cable detection), but it ends up just sitting at something like 5VDC all the time. That’s still not exactly ideal, but it’s also not likely to be a major source of interference, especially with everything else being shielded.

The first one is not a "special cable", it is a newer USB3.2 and USB4 10Gbps/20Gbps cable, recommended design. The second picture shows construction of old-style cables, they do not work well at recent speeds.

I wish I had a photo of the cable that I found glowing red hot and charring my desk when I came to work one Monday morning. I'm not buying them from a pound shop in future.

There are different types of cables. Some can be thin, some cannot be. None of them will have 24 individual wires though.
Simplest ones don't have all the wires, as they are just for USB 2.0 and are rated for 3A current. They can be very thin and very flexible. 5 wires is enough.
The most complex cables support video transfer in DP Alt Mode and are rated for 5A current and may contain active signal buffers or converters at one or both ends. They can be quite thick and stiff to bend to protect the delicate high speed cabling from damage, as too tight bends ruin the high speed properties.
It still does not require 24 wires, as typically the four VBUS and four GND pins do not have individual wires and due to connector being flippable you only need one USB 2 wire pair. So 4 HS data pairs, 1 SBU/AUX pair, 1 USB2 pair, VBUS, GND, CC and VCONN is only 16 wires.
The supply wires that carry high current are typically much thicker than the high speed data wires that can be very thin.
Also in general you need thicker wires if you intend to make a longer cable and thinner wires if you make a shorter cable.

Reminds me of SCART, where some cables had the full 22 wires (and were thick), others had only 2 wires... we had the shitty video cable issue well before Type-C was invented.

Counting the shields, I think the cables in this answer have at least 24 wires.

@JPhi1618 Following that logic, there may be one drain wire or one per shield. And each conductor may consist of e.g. 7 wire strands per conductor.

@user1686 And then there was IDE, where internal ribbon cables had 80 wires for 40 pins.

@FeRD it stll was a standard general purpose 80-pin ribbon cable and the 40-pin IDE specific connectors just connected every other wire to GND.
